# Delegatecall correct syntax is needed

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

There two contracts `A` and `B`. Both them have too simple code and it's because of a test, and `B` deployed before `A` deployment. `B` has a function called `modify`. `A` has a function called `caller` that takes a `delegatcall` to `modify`. But, I don't know the correct syntax for `delegatcall` and tried this in `A`:

```
<address of B>.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("modify(bytes memory)")), bytes(s)));
```

By this way, my expected change doesn't occur in state of `A`. In fact, no change occurs. I don't know why. I'm not sure about correctness of the mentioned command. Please tell me about correct syntax and command and about solution.

B:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract B{
    string name="Joe";

    function modify(bytes memory b) public {
        name=string(b);
    }
}
```

A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract A{

    string name="Kara";

    function caller(string memory s) public {
        <address of B>.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("modify(bytes memory)")), bytes(s)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("modify(bytes memory)")), bytes(s))`, try `abi.encodeWithSignature("modify(bytes memory)", bytes(s))`.

Comment: @scorpion9979 I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Still the problem is alive. No change occurs. I expect, in `A`, `Kara` be changed to a value that I insert to the `caller`. But It never changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
contract B {
    string public name="Joe";

    function modify(bytes memory b) public {
        name=string(b);
    }

}

contract A {

    string public name="Kara";

    function caller(address addr, string memory s) public {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = addr.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("modify(bytes)", s));
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Does this work for you? I removed the storage specifier `memory` from the signature as well as used a different method to encode the data.

Comment: Yes, It works. But what about `abi.encodePacked(...)`

Comment: Honestly not sure. [Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html?highlight=keccak#semantic-and-syntactic-changes) say it's not a breaking change, even though it seems like it is. Can't get it working without using `encodeWithSignature`